# mysql to check if value is more than 0

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my code. Actually it run without error but it always enter the first condition even though the value in mysql is more than 0 say for example is 10.

```
<?php
session_start();
$loginuser = $_SESSION['result'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","leavecalendar");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
$sql="SELECT leavecount from employee WHERE username = $loginuser[username]";
$resource = mysql_query($sql);
if ($resource == 0) {
echo "ajsdjsdasjd";   <----always enters here
 }
else
{
header("insert.php");
} 

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You can't use `mysql_query` with `mysqli`, you have to use `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Plus, this stands to fail `WHERE username = $loginuser[username]";`

Comment: You also have an error in you query (strings need to be quoted)

Comment: And after the query, you have to call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` (or one of the other `mysqli_fetch` functions) to get the row of results; `$resource` doesn't contain the data.

Comment: What is it with the answers lately? (not to mention questions mixing APIs)

Comment: The multitude of revisions in the question confused me enough.

Comment: @Patrick You need to go read a mysqli tutoral. There are also plenty of examples in the documentation, they show the normal way to make queries and get the results. There's no excuse for this question that has so many basic mistakes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I get the impression that, with gems like `mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","leavecalendar");`, `echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();`, and `WHERE username = $loginuser[username]` that this isn't production code. Or, at least, I really, really hope not. Let's hope this guy isn't writing bank software, or we're all doomed.

Comment: Always hard to say @ParthianShot

Comment: @Barmar - As you can see on my question....the script is kinda basic....SUPER BASIC....so it means that I'm just studying my way out of PHP but if you ask me how to do it in assembly language then it will be my pleasure to explain it to you in a matter where I'm 100% sure that you will never understand. You know a lot in mysql but I on the other hand have only an ounce of knowledge in mysql as well in php that is why I'm asking. But with this kind of attitude that you though of me as a no brain asking some silly questions, then I might say that you should not be here.

Comment: this is not a bank software....this is actually a code handed to me by my sister which I found more interesting to study. This has nothing to do with any companies worlwide and I can assure you that. That is why I'm messing with it. Think before commenting.

Comment: Get a thicker skin. I've been helping people on the Internet for decades. I answer dozens of questions a week, sometimes even for languages or libraries I've never used. You need to learn to accept criticism.

Comment: @Patrick You have my apologies. I was making a joke, and I will grant it may have been in poor taste.

Comment: grabbing popcorn. do continue ;)

Comment: It was not criticism. Criticism is used to make a developer better. I'm not a developer in php......I'm SO NEW HERE in php.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are mixing api's. Dont mix `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*`. Just stick with `mysqli_*`.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","leavecalendar"); // mysqli
$resource = mysql_query($sql); // mysql
```

Second, since you are using `mysqli_*` now, just use prepared statements.

```
$sql="SELECT leavecount from employee WHERE username = $loginuser[username]";
```

Third, dont compare the result set to zero, instead, check how many rows did the result return.

```
$resource = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ($resource == 0) {
```

Consider this example:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['result'])) {
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","leavecalendar");
    $loginuser = $_SESSION['result'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT leavecount from employee WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $loginuser);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // if it has results
        header("Location: insert.php");
    } else {
        // if it has NO results
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- **Problems**

**1)** You can not use

```
mysql_query($query)
```

For mysqli

**2)**

```
"SELECT leavecount from employee WHERE username = $loginuser[username]"
```

The username should be single quoted or double quoted.
For ex: `"SELECT leavecount from employee WHERE username = 'dineshrawat'";`

- **Solution**

  ```
  <?php
  session_start();
  $loginuser = $_SESSION['result'];
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","leavecalendar");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
  $sql="SELECT leavecount from employee WHERE username = $loginuser[username]";
  $resource = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  if ($resource == 0) { // If there is no record in result set
  echo "No record found";
   }
  else
  {
  header("insert.php");
  } 

  mysqli_close($con);
  ?>
  ```